# Will the number range affects obviously the weight of this feature in neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, logistic-regression

My neural network has dozens of features. Some of them has the value range between 0 to 1. While some of them has a very huge range, from 0 to million. I concatenate them without any weight setting in tensorflow and pass them to the LR layer. What I want to ask is that whether the range of features themselves affect the weight or the speaking right in the LR layer for classification task ? That is to say,  features which have huge value range, can have more influence in the network? If it is, what can I do to modify the neural network ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your neural network to assign more importance to high values features, you should probably do **Data Normalization.**

sklearn has what you are looking for as a readymade function call, you can look for it [here.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-normalization)

Also, neural networks after infinite amount of training would understand on it own that high valued features are important or not, but that will take enormously long time. It is always a good idea to preprocess your data to reduce training period.